# Python v3 Logging

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x

I could use this code below on Python 2. I tried it on Python 3 and I got an error. Anyone could explain why?

Code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

LOG_FILENAME = 'poller.log'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
poll_logger = logging.getLogger('pollerLog')

# Add the log message handler to the logger
log_rotator = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, when='d', interval=1, backupCount=5, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
poll_logger.addHandler(log_rotator)

# Roll over on application start
poll_logger.handlers[0].doRollover()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logR.py", line 10, in <module>
    log_rotator = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, when='d', interval=1, back
upCount=5, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
  File "C:\LynxApps\Python31\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 206, in __init__
    t = os.stat(filename)[ST_MTIME]
NameError: global name 'ST_MTIME' is not defined
```

I checked out the documents below and I don't see any difference:

Python v2 --> http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

Python v3 --> http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=logging#timedrotatingfilehandler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in Python 3.1.3 (see the [issue on bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue10810)).

Supposedly it's fixed in Python 3.2.

Comment: Ahh.. that made sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The bugfix will also be included in 3.1.4, which should be released some time in the next few months.